# MySQL indexes on temp tables

Tags: mysql, index, join, temporary-tables

I am trying to perform joins between two temporary tables, creating an index on the join key for each temp table. However, when I `EXPLAIN` the join, the row estimates always seem to come out vastly incorrect - the first table will have roughly the correct number, but the second table always returns `rows=1`. Upon digging further, it seems that MySQL hasn't properly done any key distribution analysis on the created indexes. `SHOW INDEX` returns the total number of rows, not the number of unique keys. Only after I force an `ANALYZE TABLE` on both tables, all the numbers are much more representative of the data.

Interestingly, this whole ordeal doesn't occur with regular, non-temporary tables. After creating the indexes, `SHOW INDEX` and `EXPLAIN` both return reasonable numbers immediately.

Is there a reason this is happening? For now, I will move forward with the calls to `ANALYZE TABLE`, as getting an accurate estimate of rows is important for my use case, and it doesn't seem to have much added overhead. However, it would be nice to know why this is happening, and if there are any oversights to the approach I'm taking.

EDIT: Here's an example of the problem I'm describing:

I've created an example table as such:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    age INT
);
```

And inserted records with 5 unique names, of which there are ~20 records per name. I then copy these values over into an identical (temporary) `t2`.

I then create indexes on both `t1` and `t2` (on the single column `name`), and run the following `EXPLAIN`:

```sql
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref          | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | NULL       | ALL  | i1            | NULL | NULL    | NULL         |  100 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | NULL       | ref  | i2            | i2   | 203     | test.t1.name |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Note the row estimate for `t2` is only 1, whereas after I run `ANALYZE TABLE t1, t2;` I get the following `EXPLAIN`:

```sql
mysql> explain select * from t1 use index(i) join t2 use index(i) on t1.name=t2.name;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref          | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | NULL       | ALL  | i1            | NULL | NULL    | NULL         |  100 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | NULL       | ref  | i2            | i2   | 203     | test.t1.name |   20 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+--------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

The row estimates become 100 for `t1` and 20 for `t2`, which is much more accurate. If I create the tables as non-temporary though, the `ANALYZE TABLE` step is not necessary to get the more accurate estimates.

Comment: Is "rows=1" coming from Explain?  Please show us `CREATE TABLEs` and the query and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  I think I can explain what you are seeing, but I need those details to be sure.

Comment: @RickJames Yes it's coming from the explain. I've gone ahead and edited the post with an example with the details you asked. Thanks!

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` says that there is a `KEY(name)` called `i2` on `t2`.  At that point, "1" is a reasonable value.

Comment: But "1" is not nearly as good an estimate as is achieved on non-temporary tables. I know the `EXPLAIN` is using the index, but I'm wondering about the distinction between key distribution analyses performed on temporary tables vs. normal tables upon index creation.

Comment: You have an example of the other Explain?

Comment: Yes, just added to the post. It gives "20" for the second table's row estimate, which notably is the estimate immediately achieved on non-temporary tables (without having to `ANALYZE TABLE`)

Comment: Only 100 rows in the table?  I would not be concerned about the metrics that Explain provides.  They may not be indicative of a million-row table.

Comment: My concern though is that the same behavior is scaling up to joins with sizes in the millions. Still "1" returned in the second table's estimate (implying a join size underestimated by many orders of magnitude), until the `ANALYZE TABLE` call is made, and the estimates become much more accurate (within max one order of magnitude). I want to detect when these dangerously large joins are about to happen, using MySQL's built-in `max_join_size`, but these bad estimates have prevented that from working effectively.

Comment: Note the change in 8.0.31:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_join_size

Comment: Perhaps the solution is to do `ANALYZE` once after the initial load of any table.

Comment: Could you actually explain the change for 8.0.31? I came across this before but was unsure of the distinction. Is the change from caring about rows examined to now caring about rows read/accessed? What's the difference here?

Comment: I think that "rows examined" = "rows read" = "rows accessed".  And that is a good metric for judging how long a query will take.  A better metric might be "blocks read", especially if all the data is not cached in the buffer_pool.  And, no, I can't explain the change in .31.  Nor do I have any experience with `max_join_size`.  Most users leave it at [effectively] infinity (2^64).